# Null Reference Exception while login with facebook using xamarin.auth in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I've implemented Facebook login using `xamarin.auth` in my Xamarin forms application. It works fine in Android, but in iOS it raises `NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION`.

Here is my class in `PCL`:

```
public class FBLogin : ContentPage
{
    public FBLogin()
    {
        //Page is Rendered in CustomRenderer for IOS and Android    
    }
    public static async Task LoginSuccess()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomeScreen())
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#009AD6"),
            BarTextColor = Color.White,
        };
    }
}
```

This is how I wrote the custom renderer in iOS:

```
public class FBLoginRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: OAuthSettings.AppID,
            scope: OAuthSettings.Scope,
            authorizeUrl: new Uri(OAuthSettings.AutherizeURL),
            redirectUrl: new Uri(OAuthSettings.RedirectURL));
            auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                DismissViewController(true, null);
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    await FBLogin.LoginSuccess();
                }
                else
                {
                    NavigationController.PopViewController(false);
                }
            };
            PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in solving this issue? I've implemented the same way of code in a sample project which worked fine but not working when I integrate to my project.

Output: after the Facebook login application redirects to my desired screen the `NULL REFERENFCE EXCEPTION` error occurs at the end of `auth.completed` event.

Comment: i know this code is very abstract to answer my question, but this is the only code i used in my project for facebook login. i debugged my code and the exception raises at end of the event auth.completed at closing bracket of the event '};' there is no complex code in that event just a page navigation. its navigating to that page but at the closing bracket of the event null reference exception raised..

Comment: what line you are getting exception on?

Comment: at the auth completed event closing bracket }; i  get exception